# .htaccess mask domain directory to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, seo, multilingual, tld

I'm having a multilingual website with primary domain "example.com".
When you select english language then you are at "example.com/en/".

I'm focusing SEO for UK and I have the domain "example.co.uk" parked on my main domain.
What I want to do is, when someone is visiting "example.co.uk" to view the content of "example.com/en/" **without the "/en/"**.
All the other links should be the same

```
i.e. "example.co.uk/servicepage" equals to "example.com/en/servicepage".
```

I have tried a couple of solutions but none of them worked for me.
I'm making a new question here, so I can have a clear answer, since my main goal is SEO and I don't want to make a fatal mistake on that.

Thank you all!